# SQLite .db file is not being removed/renamed even after closing the connection of that particular file

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.io.file

I'm using SQLite3 database for a small level system. The problem is that when I try to rename the db file using IO file system, System.IO returns an exception that the file is being used by another process however I've already closed the connection using connection.Close() method. I searched on this topic but cold not find any thing useful for me. Someone please suggest me the right way to release an SQLite connection..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I learned programming with SQLite is that closing the connection is simply not good enough. You need to wrap everything in a `using` block. Make sure your `SQLiteConnection` object is wrapped in a `using` block, your `SQLiteCommand` is wrapped in a `using` block and your `SQLiteDataReader` is wrapped in a `using` block. Your code should look similar to this:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Connection = connection;

        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't this just do the same thing as closing the connection?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn - No. Wrapping the code in a `using` block will not only close the connection if it's open, but it will also tell the garbage collector that you are done with the memory that the object is using and it should immediately clean up and dispose of all objects being used by this object.